# Integration of $\sin x/x$

Tags: integration

How to evaluate $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x} x \, dx$

I have tried substitutions and integration by parts, but unable to integrate it.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral